# NodeJS - Turn On and Off Tourch/Flashlight in mobile Android/IPhone

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, mediastream

I have a project in nodeJS which I use on System as well as on Mobile.

I need to perform the below steps -
 1. Add a button to turn on/off the flashlight.
 2. The button should only be displayed if the feature is supported by
    the phone and the browser
 3. The light should default to off

When I am using the below-mentioned code it is enabling my WebCam flash from my System and it is not working on my mobile.

Flash Light On/Off

```
//Test browser support
const SUPPORTS_MEDIA_DEVICES = 'mediaDevices' in navigator;

if (SUPPORTS_MEDIA_DEVICES) {
  //Get the environment camera (usually the second one)
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {

    const cameras = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'videoinput');

    if (cameras.length === 0) {
      throw 'No camera found on this device.';
    }
    const camera = cameras[cameras.length - 1];

    // Create stream and get video track
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    }).then(stream => {
      const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      track.applyConstraints({
        advanced: [{torch: false}]
      });
      //Create image capture object and get camera capabilities
      const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track)
      const photoCapabilities = imageCapture.getPhotoCapabilities().then(() => {

        //todo: check if camera has a torch

        //let there be light!
        const btn = document.querySelector('.switch');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            isTorchOn = !isTorchOn;
          track.applyConstraints({
            advanced: [{torch: isTorchOn}]
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  //The light will be on as long the track exists
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: If your code needs to work on every mobile I don not think this can be achieved. As far as I know only on Chrome it is possible to access the Camera controls via Browser.

Comment: Yes, Chrome will work for me. I am accessing it through chrome in my mobile.

Answer (score 2):

For Web RTC,
use this for Torch support check at Device

```
var imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);

var photoCapability = imageCapture.getPhotoCapabilities();
```

use this for Torch support check at browser

```
var mediaCapabilities = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints ()
 
 if (mediaCapabilities.torch && photoCapability.fillLightMode.length > 0){
          document.getElementById('torchButton').classList.remove("hidden");
          document.getElementById('torchButton').classList.add("block");
          console.log("Torch is enabled");
      }
```

then based on call in function

```
function startTorch(){
    var torchCheckBox = document.getElementById("torchButton");
    if(torchCheckBox.checked == true){
    videoTrack.applyConstraints({
        advanced: [{torch: true}]
      }).then(function() {
        //Do Success code here
      }).catch(handleError);
    }
    else{
        videoTrack.applyConstraints({
            advanced: [{torch: false}]
          }).then(function() {
            //success code here  
          }).catch(handleError);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Iphone Safari browser doesn't support flash light functionality